# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:oracle/j2ee/ws/common/jaxws/ServiceDelegateImpl

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, soa, oracle-adf, business-process-management

I am using BPM API to retrieve a list of task assigned to a particular user. But, While running the class file I am getting following error:--

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/j2ee/ws/common/jaxws/ServiceDelegateImpl
    at oracle.bpm.client.BPMServiceClientFactory.<init>(BPMServiceClientFactory.java:102)
    at oracle.bpm.client.BPMServiceClientFactory.getInstance(BPMServiceClientFactory.java:144)
    at project3.Fixture.getBPMServiceClientFactory(Fixture.java:33)
    at project3.Fixture.getBPMServiceClient(Fixture.java:49)
    at project3.GetProcessInstances.testGetProcessInstances(GetProcessInstances.java:29)
    at project3.GetProcessInstances.main(GetProcessInstances.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.j2ee.ws.common.jaxws.ServiceDelegateImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:305)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:246)
    ... 6 more
```

I have already added the following Jar file to my project:--

1. Oracle.bpm.runtime.jar
2. Oracle.bpm.client.jar
3. Bpm-services.jar
4. Wsclient.jar

But still the issue is not resolved..

Any Suggestion??????

Comment: Can you supply also the source code that gives the error?

Comment: Have you seen this http://my-java-planet.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-resolve-javalangnoclassdeffounde.html and also tell that which IDE you are using?I guess it should be JDEV... seems that your wsclient.jar isn't loading properly

Comment: I m Using Jdeveloper 11.1.1.5

Comment: Hey Freak Kindly tell me what should I do now.....My developement is stuck over here...It is very Urgent....

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the reason it is not working you should be using the TaskQueryService provided by Oracle out of the box.